# Is there a way to set the primary color as the background color to the Layout component using UI Kitten?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I'm building a login screen using [UI Kitten 4.0](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/), and I want to set a background color to the [Layout component](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/layout/overview#layout) to be the primary color of the current theme.

There isn't any reference on the documentation about this as it is on the [Button component](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/button/api#button) API page.

I would like to achieve something like the code below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { Layout, Text } from "react-native-ui-kitten"

export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
          <Layout primary>
            <Text>Log in</Text>
          </Layout>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also have built-in API to access theme properties. [Check the Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@art.yorsh/ui-kitten---theme-properties)

Answer (score 1):

- There is no 'primary' property in the "Layout" component. You can check the API in the documentation: https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/layout/api#layout
- You can customize the "backgroundColor" style directly through the "style" property: `<Layout style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>` or through mapping customization: https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/design-system/custom-component-mapping#prepare-the-boilerplate